# TortoiseHG, fork with subrepos - force commit&push .hgsubstate only

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

There is public repo on mercurial (not mine). It contains two subrepos. I've made a fork for both main repo nad two subrepos. I want to create pull requests from time to time, but I can't make subrepos work properly.
When I clone my forked repo, it will be downloaded, but two subrepos will remain original, not my forked one. If I'll replace them with forked, I won't be able to make a pull request cos I don't want to switch original repo to my subrepos. But I want to change both repo and subrepo.
Once I've found a solution. I've modified hgrc file in .hg folder of subrepo.

```
It was:
[paths]
default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/originator/subrepo
```

It become:

```
[paths]
Me = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/Me/subrepo
Original = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/originator/subrepo
```

It was working exactly as it should. I've changed code, pushed to my subrepo, created pull request for subrepo. Then I've pushed changes in my main repo and it simply worked. .hgsubstate is now reffering to commit that exist on forked repo, but not on original one. When orignator will megre both pull requests, everything would work.

Is I said, it worked before, but not now. For some weird reason I can't just push .hgsubstate that point to new subrepo revision that exists on forked subrepo. I simply can't include it in commit. I click "commit", but in result commit it's not included. And I don't know how to force is being included - HG too "smart" about it. Also TortoiseHG marks my subrepo as dirty. But if I'll try to add both .hgsubstate and my dirty repo, it for some reason tries to push changes to originator's repo. It seems like my HG just can't commit .hgsubstate without pushing changes to subrepo on itself.
Any way to solve this? Everything I want is to commit and push .hgsubstate without doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Did you adjust your .hgsub accordingly so that it works for both, your local paths as well as the remote paths to which you push to the server?

It's advisable to add to your .hgsub sections which describe the paths in an absolute sense. I used to struggle with that when I had the subrepos as the same level in the dir structure on the server but wanted them as sub-dirs on my own computer. It helped me to add to .hgsub a subpaths section:

```
[subpaths]
ssh://user@host.org/path/subrepo1 = ssh://user@host.org/subrepo1
ssh://user@host.org/path/subrepo2 = ssh://user@host.org/subrepo2

/home/user/project/subrepo1 = /home/user/subrepo1
/home/user/project/subrepo2 = /home/user/subrepo2

project/subrepo1 = subrepo1
project/subrepo2 = subrepo2
```

Comment: That would help me to work with my repo, but it wasn't actualy a problem. Problem is that if I modify .hgsub, modified version will be provided in pull request. That is a problem - I can't just modify .hgsub.